# array reduce accumulator as an empty array, push not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is the accumulator.push  not valid? accumulator is an empty array!? If i use the predefined variable `flarArray`, things work just fine!! I know that if no initial value is included in the reduce callback, then it will use the first item in the array (which in my case will be an object) to be the accumulator, but if I tell it to start off as an array as the accumulator, what is the problem with that?

```
const profiles = [
  {
    id: 1,
    userID: '1',
    favoriteMovieID: '1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    userID: '2',
    favoriteMovieID: '1',
  }
];

const users = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jane Cruz',
    userName: 'coder',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Matthew Johnson',
    userName: 'mpage',
  }
};

const movies = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Planet Earth 1',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Selma',
  }
};
let flatArray = [];
const flattenedProfiles = profiles.reduce(function(accumulator, currentProfile) {  
  return accumulator.push({id: currentProfile.id, name: users[currentProfile.id].name, favoriteMovie: movies[currentProfile.favoriteMovieID].name})
},[]);
```

Comment: The `push()` method returns the new length of the array, so in your callback you're returning an integer instead of the accumulator. You need to change `return accumulator.push({ ... })` into `accumulator.push({ ... }); return accumulator;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return `accumulator`, instead you are returning the return value of `push` function which is the size of the array after adding the new item. In next iteration, you are calling `push` function on an integer

```
const flattenedProfiles = profiles.reduce((acc, curr) => {  
  acc.push({
     id: curr.id,
     name: users[curr.id].name,
     favoriteMovie: movies[curr.favoriteMovieID].name
  });

  return acc;
},[]);
```

Comment: I see, trying to return while an array is still filling up. I will remember to manufacture the array and once done `return` the final array!

Answer (score 2):

`Array.push` returns the new length of the array when inside the return of callback of `reduce` you are returning the new length on which you can't do next push operation. Use `Array.concat` instead or after `Array.push` also return the array.

```
const flattenedProfilesPush = profiles.reduce((acc, curr) => {  
    acc.push({
        id: curr.id,
    })
    return acc
},[])


const flattenedProfilesConcat = profiles.reduce((acc, curr) =>  
    acc.concat({
        id: curr.id,
    }),[]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you return `accumulator.push()`. This returns the length of the array, so your next accumulator is gonna be a number instead of an array.

I would better return an array and use spread operator on the accumulator.

```js
const profiles = [
  {
    id: 1,
    userID: '1',
    favoriteMovieID: '1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    userID: '2',
    favoriteMovieID: '1',
  }
];

const users = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jane Cruz',
    userName: 'coder',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Matthew Johnson',
    userName: 'mpage',
  }
};

const movies = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Planet Earth 1',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Selma',
  }
};
let flatArray = [];
const flattenedProfiles = profiles.reduce(function(accumulator, currentProfile) {  
  return [...accumulator, {id: currentProfile.id, name: users[currentProfile.id].name, favoriteMovie: movies[currentProfile.favoriteMovieID].name}]
},[]);

console.log(flattenedProfiles);
```